# Github Rest API: Bulk search with multiple issue numbers

Tags: api, rest, github

Need to do bulk search with multiple issue numbers using Github Rest API

Comment: Are you asking how to make one request that contains data about multiple issues?  If so, you can't with the REST API; you need to use the GraphQL API.

Comment: Also I need to do bulk issue search in a date range is it possible using Github Rest API